# Java: Purpose of double \\ characters?

Tags: java

```
command = command.replaceAll("\\{player}", e.getPlayer().getName());
```

What is the purpose of the "\\" in "\\{player}" within that line?

Why doesn't the programmer just do "{player}" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an escape sequence. Since the `{` character has a special meaning in a regex, it needs to be escaped to signify you actually meant the literal `{`.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash are usually to "escape" characters. Characters that usually can be used for regex. In this case, the {} can be interpreted as regex (which you can utilize for string manipulations), hence why you'd have to escape them for your {} to be interpreted as a literal brackets instead of reg ex.

Answer (score 1):

"\ with some other characters have special meanings.
For example, \n moves to next line \t writes "tab" character and so on.
Because of this, if you really want to write \ in your code like, `"c:\someFolder\someFile"` you should use `"C:\\someFolder\\someFile"` 
\ called escape character 
If you write

```
String text ="firstname\lastname";
```

compiler gives you an error "illegal escape character"
It means that you should not use"\" alone in your code.
Happy coding!